# How to show two div when user scroll down using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please tell me how to show two divs when the user scroll down using jquery.I want to push values on the array .Is it possible to add a div on the bottom.As we add when user scroll to top ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gbd3z/2/

```
$("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {
    // top
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0 && pages.length) {
        console.log("up"+pages);
        var stringLoad = "page_" + pages.length;
        $("<div id='" + stringLoad + "'>" + pages.pop() + "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));
        $('#fullContainer').children().slice(3).remove()
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("down");
    }
});
```

Comment: to add a div use append(myDiv) declair myDiv befor... like "var myDiv = 'bla bla' than find scroll end and add it. same backwords

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but does this do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/luken/R24TH/

```
var pages = [page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4,page_5];
var lastLoadedPageIndex = -1;
var $container = $('#fullContainer');
addNextPageToContainer();

function addNextPageToContainer () {
    lastLoadedPageIndex++;
    if (lastLoadedPageIndex < pages.length) {
       $( '<div id="page_'
                  + lastLoadedPageIndex
                  + '" class="page">' 
                  + pages[lastLoadedPageIndex]
                  + '</div>'
       ).slideDown().appendTo( $container );
   }
}

$container.scroll(function(){
    if ($container.scrollTop() === 0 && pages.length) {
        console.log("up");
    } else if ($container.scrollTop() >= $container[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("down");
        addNextPageToContainer();
    }
 });
```